# How to change the onclick button become onclick and longclick together?

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

This is the main activity. How can i edit the code so that the button can become onclick and long click? I would like to make the button perform a task when clicked while it performs another task while I long click it.

```
public class AndroidRemoteActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private TextView logview;
private Button connect, deconnect;
private ImageView forwardArrow, backArrow, rightArrow, leftArrow, stop;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;

private String[] logArray = null;

private BtInterface bt = null;

static final String TAG = "Chihuahua";
static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 3;

//This handler listens to messages from the bluetooth interface and adds them to the log
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        String data = msg.getData().getString("receivedData");
        addToLog(data);            
    }
};

//this handler is dedicated to the status of the bluetooth connection
final Handler handlerStatus = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        int status = msg.arg1;
        if(status == BtInterface.CONNECTED) {
            addToLog("Connected");
        } else if(status == BtInterface.DISCONNECTED) {
            addToLog("Disconnected");
        }
    }
};

//handles the log view modification
//only the most recent messages are shown
private void addToLog(String message){
    for (int i = 1; i < logArray.length; i++){
        logArray[i-1] = logArray[i];
    }
    logArray[logArray.length - 1] = message;

    logview.setText("");
    for (int i = 0; i < logArray.length; i++){
        if (logArray[i] != null){
            logview.append(logArray[i] + "\n");
        }
    }       
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_remote);

    //first, inflate all layout objects, and set click listeners

    logview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.logview);
    //I chose to display only the last 3 messages
    logArray = new String[3];

    connect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);
    connect.setOnClickListener(this);

    deconnect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deconnect);
    deconnect.setOnClickListener(this);

    forwardArrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.forward_arrow);
    forwardArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
    backArrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.back_arrow);
    backArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
    rightArrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.right_arrow);
    rightArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
    leftArrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.left_arrow);
    leftArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
    stop = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    stop.setOnClickListener(this);
}

//it is better to handle bluetooth connection in onResume (ie able to reset when changing screens)
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //first of all, we check if there is bluetooth on the phone
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        // Device does not support Bluetooth
        Log.v(TAG, "Device does not support Bluetooth");
    }
    else{
        //Device supports BT
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            //if Bluetooth not activated, then request it 
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
        else{
            //BT activated, then initiate the BtInterface object to handle all BT communication
            bt = new BtInterface(handlerStatus, handler);
        }
    }
}

//called only if the BT is not already activated, in order to activate it
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent moreData){
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            //BT activated, then initiate the BtInterface object to handle all BT communication
            bt = new BtInterface(handlerStatus, handler);
        }
        else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
            Log.v(TAG, "BT not activated");
        else
            Log.v(TAG, "result code not known");
    }
    else{
        Log.v(TAG, "request code not known");       
    }
 }

//handles the clicks on various parts of the screen
//all buttons launch a function from the BtInterface object
   @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == connect) {
        addToLog("Trying to connect");
        bt.connect();           
    } 
    else if(v == deconnect) {
        addToLog("closing connection");
        bt.close();         
    }
    else if(v == forwardArrow) {
        //addToLog("Move Forward");
        bt.sendData("F");
    }
    else if(v == backArrow) {
        //addToLog("Move back");
        bt.sendData("B");
    }
    else if(v == rightArrow) {
        //addToLog("Turn Right");
        bt.sendData("R");
    }
    else if(v == leftArrow) {
        //addToLog("Turn left");
        bt.sendData("L");
    }
    else if(v == stop) {
        //addToLog("Stopping");
        bt.sendData("S");
    }

}
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
   protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);

     setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_remote);

     final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forward_arrow);
     button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
         public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
             if (v==forwardArrow){
                 bt.sendData("f");
             }
             return true;
         }
     });
   }
}
   }
```

Comment: use `onLongClickListener` and `onClickListener`.

Comment: Do you want to trigger `Onclick` and `OnLongClickListner` at the same time..?

Answer (score 1):

use on click listner and on long click listner

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
     button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    })
```